# Angular tree component error while compiling

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am trying to use [Angular tree component](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/getting-started) but when I do everything that is described on getting started page I get following error "Property 'nodes' does not exist on type 'TreeViewComponent'.

here is my tree-view-component.html

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Tree">

        <tree-root [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options"></tree-root>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

and here is my tree-view-component.ts

```
export class App {
    nodes = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'root1',
        children: [
          { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
          { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'root2',
        children: [
          { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'child2.2',
            children: [
              { id: 7, name: 'subsub' }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    options = {};
  }
```

Comment: Did you `import { TreeModule } from 'angular-tree-component';`?

Comment: Yes in app.module.ts I did this "import { TreeModule } from 'angular-tree-component';"as it is described in getting started page

Comment: Why is your class called `App`. It should be `TreeViewComponent`?

Comment: I did not noticed fixed the name and I will try It now thanks

Comment: Okay It works now I can't believe It such a stupid mistake thank you :) Have a nice day :)